# Ошибка E0963. Класс ругается на конструктор

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, функции, конструктор

Возникла проблема с кодом, не знаю, как ее решить. Пишет, что нельзя указывать тип возвращаемого значения для конструктора. На всякий случай сообщу, что мне необходимо, чтоб оно мониторило book[1] на поиск слова "Program" и в случае, если найдет, выводило дату и автора (book[2],book[3]).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Book{
private:
    string book[3][16];
public:
    Book();
    void founder() {};
}

Book::Book() {
    string book[3][16] = {
    {"Program","Program","Something","Noting","","Program","Noting","Something","Something","Anything","Program","Noting","Noting","Something","Noting","Program"},
    {"12.03.2004","12.03.2009","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003"},
    {"Jack","Jack","George","George","George","George","Jack","George","George","George","Jack","George","George","Jack","George","Jack"}
    };
};

void Book::founder() {
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
        if (book[1][i] == "Program"){cout << "Date: " << book[2][i] << "Autor: " << book[3][i] << endl; };
    };
};

void main() {
    Book b;
    b.founder();
}
```

Comment: `void founder() {};` замените на `void founder();`. Помимо этого у вас ничего в класс не добавляется, в конструкторе вы присваиваете данные локально переменной. которая уничтожается при выходе из конструктора. А еще после класса должна стоять точка с запятой. `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ваш код в точности такой, то по сути у вас написано

```
class Book {...} Book::Book(){}
```

Т.е. объявлен конструктор, возвращающий этот самый `class Book`. А конструктор ничего возвращать не должен... Итак, нужна точка с запятой после объявления класса.

После этого компилятор совершенно справедливо поясняет, что `book` в конструкторе скрывает имя `book` в классе - т.е. то, что вы написали в конструкторе

```
Book::Book() {
    string book[3][16] = {
```

не имеет *никакого отношения* к полю `book` в классе, которое так и остается не инициализированным.

Исправляем -

```
Book::Book():book{
    {"Program","Program","Something","Noting","","Program","Noting","Something","Something","Anything","Program","Noting","Noting","Something","Noting","Program"},
    {"12.03.2004","12.03.2009","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003","12.03.2003"},
    {"Jack","Jack","George","George","George","George","Jack","George","George","George","Jack","George","George","Jack","George","Jack"}
}
{
};
```

Теперь выползает очередная ошибка - что ваша `void Book::founder()` уже имеет текст реализации - и в самом деле, ведь в классе вы ее не просто объявили, а определили, как имеющую пустое тело. А теперь - непустое. Компилятор на ruSO не участвует, понимать, что программист *хотел*, не умеет. Исправляем и эту ошибку, убирая `{}` у функции в объявлении класса.

Теперь компилятору не нравится `void` у `main()` - и его можно понять: стандарт ведь требует `int`.

И вот только после этого код компилируется.

Но, скорее всего, не работает (хотя, может, вы хотели именно этого - пишете же, что "мониторить `book[1]` надо, т.е. искать `"Program"` среди дат...). Хотя бы потому, что все элементы массивов нумеруются с 0, так что вы благополучно опускаете первый элемент, а в цикле выходите за пределы массива. И сравниваете, кстати, вторую строку массива `book`, с датами...

И только переписав цикл как

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    if (book[0][i] == "Program")
        cout << "Date: " << book[1][i] << " Autor: " << book[2][i] << endl;
};
```

мы получим какой-то вывод.

Итак, у вас как минимум 4 ошибки. Причем о трех из них, которые мешали компиляции, компилятор сообщал вполне доступным языком...